# Non-null variable evaluating as null

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a variable with a value; however, it is evaluated as being null

[image]

I suspect it may be because the variable was initialized with:

```
 FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
```

If this is the case, is there a way to get the object into a good state?  Maybe though reflection?

Comment: Could it be an issue with your code overriding the Equals method on EntitySlot?

Comment: Shouldn't be possible. Could there be a symbol collision? Do you have any two of {property, field, local variable, extension method} where they are both named `entitySlot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `EntitySlot` (or a base class of `EntitySlot`) is overriding `Equals` which is incorrectly marking the `entitySlot` instance and `null` as equal. You can test this out by comparing the result of `.Equals()` and `.ReferenceEquals()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not null - you can clearly see the properties initialized.

But your equality check is showing null - please check your Equals method overload as Cameron has mentioned.